# ReadOnly PV on multiple clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-pvc

I am a newbie to kubernetes. I have multiple cluster and each cluster has multiple namespaces. We want to mount a NFS as ReadOnly PV on all clusters. The files on the NFS will be shared across all clusters and across all namespaces within each cluster and among all pods within each namespace. If any pod is destroyed, the PVC must still be available to other pods in the same namespace. How can I achieve it?

TIA,

Amit

Answer (score 2):

You are right, you can use the NFS and share it across the multiple Kubernetes clusters.

As NFS you can use the GlusterFS : https://www.gluster.org/

You can run the GlusterFS on separate VMs and create a cluster of it so that way it would be easy to manage and creating a connection with other K8s clusters also.

Multiple VMs suggested due to managing the copy of content data and HA.

You can read more at : https://russmediaequitypartners.com/news/tech-case-study-kubernetes/